# Exponent of Lewis number in coupled heat-mass transfer problem

Tags: thermodynamics, mass, diffusion, convection

I am writing a small model of the coupling of heat and mass transfers in the nose and mouth. By solving the heat and mass balance equations, Lewis number expression appears that allows for coupling those equations.
I sent it to a colleague for proof reading, and he gave me back a relation between the ratio of the thicknesses of heat transfer on mass transfer, such as

$$ \frac{\delta_h}{\delta_m} \approx Le^{\frac{1}{2}} $$

I agree that the Lewis definition implies a relation between the ratio of thicknesses and Lewis to the n$^{\text{th}}$ power but the choice of 1/2 power remains unclear for me. Furthermore, although I am not an expert in transport phenomena at all, the literature seems to cite a general 1/3 exponent rather than 1/2...

Thanks for insights.

Comment: It depends on the flow regime.  For laminar flow in a tube, the exponent is 1/3, but for plug flow in a tube, the exponent is 1/2.  It depends on how the velocity is behaving near the wall.

Comment: Thank you, makes sense in my problem! Do we have good reference covering that aspect? Thanks

Comment: Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot is a keeper.